# Re-using a multiple entry visa, do I need to document my stay to the customs officer?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, germany, paperwork

I have been to France with schengen visa before 2 months.  I am planning to go to Germany now. The visa is still valid and it is multiple entry. That should be sufficient for my Germany travel. Do I need any letter or details of my stay ?

Comment: There's a general recommendation that anytime you arrive in the zone from outside of the zone to bring all the pertinent documentation you used when you applied for the visa. It's not a rule and challenges do not occur each and every time, but the recommendation can be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To give this question an answer: No it's not really necessary, but it's recommended to do so.