# Re-entering UK on multiplie entry general visitor visa of 6 months

Tags: visas, pakistani-citizens

I came to UK on a 6 month multiple-entry general visitor visa issued on 26 Oct 2015 to appear in a professional exam and meet some relatives. My return ticket was of 2 Jan 2016 but I have to go back early due to some family issue back home.

In the mean time there was a job offer in which I was offered an interview so I am planning to back to UK on 13 Jan 2016 for about a week to attend interview and then return back. My visitor visa is valid until April 2016.

My question is, will it be a problem during my re entering to UK and can I come on the same general visitor visa to attend an interview?

I live originally in Pakistan

Comment: Is this issued as a Standard Visitor Visa because from the dates you mentioned it is unlikely that it is a General Visitor Visa

Comment: @skv, nice call...  it's a standard; they stopped issuing generals on 24 April 2015.  The OP is using the old terminology or has the issue date wrong.

Comment: In theory, it seems, you can do this.  The big unknown in the equation is your landing interview.  The entry clearance officer might decide that you are an overstay risk and refuse to admit you.  This is perhaps more likely given that the purpose of your trip is a job interview.  Therefore, you should bring evidence that you will return to your home country.

Comment: @phoog, please convert that to an answer; it's bookable. A miniscule nitpick from a pedant: ECO's work in consulates abroad; IO's work at ports and are legally empowered to remove (plus make a lot more money).

Comment: @GayotFow Thanks for the correction.  "IO" means "immigration officer," or something else?  I commented rather than answering because I do not know how serious a problem it would be for the purpose of the trip to be a job interview.  I would worry, and I know neither how justified such a worry would be nor what evidence would be helpful in overcoming any such problem.  Would it not cause the IO to discount evidence of employment back home in assessing the intention to return?

Comment: @phoog having an entry clearance reduces the landing interview to a more relaxed process, verging on a formality. For a job interview, the big question the IO (Immigration Officer) will want to know is if the company has a sponsorship permit and the OP should bring evidence of that. As for other evidence please read this comment http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59645/re-using-a-multiple-entry-visa-do-i-need-to-document-my-stay-to-the-customs-off#comment123307_59645

Comment: Not wanting to do anything illegal, but why should you even mention the interview as the purpose of the second visit, you could just quote visiting relatives and yes once you are in, it is perfectly legal for you to do an interview.

Comment: @skv what happens if the interview results in an offer?

Comment: @GayotFow  wording it in a lighter sense :) that will have to be a question on expatriates.stackexchange, on a serious note, he probably has to travel back to Pakistan and come back with a valid Tier-2 work visa sponsored by the employer?